# Why does Google Chrome refresh pages automatically

Tags: google-chrome

If I leave a page open for a long time on Google Chrome while I'm using another tab, after a while, when I go back onto the first tab, it refreshes automatically. This is annoying because I have to wait for the page to load before being able to use it. Why does it do this and how can I keep it from doing this?

Comment: It does this to manage memory. It unloads tabs you aren't using to free up memory for ones you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory is not a concern, disable automatic tab discarding by visiting:
chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding.

If enabled, tabs get automatically discarded from memory when the system memory is low. Discarded tabs are still visible on the tab strip and get reloaded when clicked on. Info about discarded tabs can be found at chrome://discards

Comment: `chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding` doesn't work anymore, but I found [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-automatic-tab-dis/dnhngfnfolbmhgealdpolmhimnoliiok/related) that disables automatic tab discarding.